# I/MultiDex: VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-multidex, google-location-services

I am trying to build an app with location. I am facing an error called "I/MultiDex: VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support". Are there any upgraded VM version than 1.6.0? If yes, then how can I upgrade VM version for multidex support. You can also suggest others way for multidex support.

This is my app level build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "example.hafiz.locationtesting"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="example.hafiz.locationtesting">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is my MainActivity.java file

```
package example.hafiz.locationtesting;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private TextView mLongitudeText;
private TextView mLatitudeText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_text);
    mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_text);

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}

protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}

protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What API level is this emulator? If you chose API Level 4, then the "1.6.0" in the error may refer to the Android version, and the multidex backport only works back to API Level 7 IIRC.

Comment: I am using API Level 19 @CommonsWare

Comment: It's not an error. "I" in "I/MultiDex" stands for "Info", and this log will always be printed on devices with API <= 19 (these devices don't have built-in support for multi-dex and patching required - which is done by the multi-dex library). What exact problem do you have?